# {status}_{post_type} does not run correctly?

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, hooks, actions

I used the hook {status}_{post_type} from the docs [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions#.7Bstatus.7D_.7Bpost_type.7D_Hook).

In the docs it said: `action will execute when a post of type {post_type} transitions to {status} from any other status.`

Here is my code:

```
function on_order_on_hold( $ID, $post) {
    # do some job
}
add_action('wc-on-hold_shop_order', 'on_order_on_hold', 10, 2);
```

And it run when the order transition from `wc-on-hold` to any other status, instead of to `wc-on-hold` from any other status.

Is the docs wrong or I misunderstand something here?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WooCommerce has its own hooks for things like this. You shouldn't rely on the underlying WordPress post-related hooks and functions when dealing with products and orders.

WooCommerce is moving towards using custom database tables for products and orders instead of custom post types and while there'll be hooks etc. added for backwards compatibility, you'll be much  better situated for that transition if you use WooCommerce's APIs.

WooCommerce has 3 hooks for handling order status transitions:

`woocommerce_order_status_{status}` runs when transitioning *to* `{status}` from any other status.

`woocommerce_order_status_{from}_to_{to}` runs when transitioning to status `{to}` from status `{from}`

`woocommerce_order_status_changed` runs when there's any transition change and receives the *from* and *to* status as the 2nd and 3rd callbacks of the callback respectively.

Note that the status in all these hooks should omit the `wc-` prefix.

```
function wpse_313075_order_on_hold( $order_id, $order ) {
    // Do something.
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_on-hold', 'wpse_313075_order_on_hold', 10, 2 );

function wpse_313075_order_pending_to_on_hold( $order_id, $order ) {
    // Do something.
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_on-hold', 'wpse_313075_order_pending_to_on_hold', 10, 2 );

function wpse_313075_order_status_changed( $order_id, $from, $to, $order ) {
    // Do something.
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'wpse_313075_order_status_changed', 10, 4 );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it is very useful. Even though, I think underlying WordPress post-related should be correct as well.

Comment: Well it's not best practice, and  it only means you might have issues in the future when products and shop orders are no longer posts. This is [not far away](https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/2018/07/17/woocommerce-custom-product-tables-beta/).

Comment: I have to thank you one more time for this valuable information. I will use these hooks instead.